# "npx create-react-app ..." audit comes with 3 high severity issues. How can I fix this?

Tags: create-react-app

I have a few react projects that were started using "npx create-react-app" and if I run "npm audit" they come back with:

```
# npm audit report

immer  <8.0.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1603
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.0.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/immer
  react-dev-utils  >=6.0.6-next.9b4009d7
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  >=2.0.6-next.9b4009d7
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    node_modules/react-scripts

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

- I have tried running `npm audit fix` and that doesn't fix the issue.
- I have tried running `npm audit fix --force` which results in even more errors.
- I have tried running `npm i immer@8.0.1` which also does not work.

I am using nvm with node version 14.15.5 and npm version 7.5.4. I recently updated nvm to the latest version (0.37.2) and changed the default to the latest node lts (14.15.5), so I believe this may be the culprit but I can't figure out how to fix these 3 vulnerabilities.

A possibility is that there's an issue with me having not moved my global packages to the newer version of node.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue; it seems to be related to `react-scripts`. I cloned an older app and slowly built it by adding modules one by one. Nothing went wrong until I added `react-scripts`.

Comment: Do you think this is an issue that everyone is getting and is therefore a problem with "npx create-react-app ..." that will be updated and fixed soon, or a problem with our setups? Which versions of node and npm are you running? Do you have "create-react-app" installed globally?

Comment: I suspect it's an issue relating to one of the packages within `npx create-react-app`, not the create package itself. I hadn't changed any versions of anything since I last used it but it was only yesterday that it started to throw errors. I've no idea who, how and when it gets fixed, sorry.

Comment: It looks like the issue has been resolved now, just requires a small download to fix. At least that was the case with me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has now been fixed. Just run `npm audit fix`.